simplified proof of Sanov's theorem ala Mohri et al.
I am trying to understand the following proof provided in "Mehryar Mohri, Afshin Rostamizadeh, and Ameet Talwalkar. Foundations of machine learning. MIT press, 2018. Appendix D.2 p.438 ". However I can't show in the last step, when plugging in back $t$ that the expression is indeed the RHS $e^{-mD(q\|p)}$
For completeness I am going to restate the theorem and the proof:
Sanov's theorem: Let $ X_1, \ldots, X_m $ be independent random variables drawn according to some distribution $\mathcal{D}$ with mean $p$ and support included in $[0,1]$. Then, for any $ q \in [0,1] $, the following inequality holds for $\hat{p} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i $:
$$
\mathbb{P}[\hat{p} \geq q] \leq e^{-m D(q\|p)},
$$
where $ D(q\|p) = q \log \frac{q}{p} + (1-q) \log \frac{1-q}{1-p} $ is the binary relative entropy of $p$ and $q$.
Proof: For any $ t > 0 $, by convexity of the function $ x \mapsto e^{tx} $, the following inequality holds for all $ x \in [0,1] $:
$$
e^{tx} = e^{t((1-x) \cdot 0 + x \cdot 1)} \leq 1 - x + e^t x.
$$
In view of that, for any $ t > 0 $, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\hat{p} \geq q] &= \mathbb{P}[e^{tm\hat{p}} \geq e^{tmq}]\\
&\leq e^{-tmq} \mathbb{E}[e^{tm\hat{p}}] \quad \text{(by Markov's inequality)}\\
&= e^{-tmq} \mathbb{E}[e^{t \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i}]\\
&= e^{-tmq} \prod_{i=1}^{m} \mathbb{E}[e^{t X_i}]\\
&\leq e^{-tmq} \prod_{i=1}^{m} \mathbb{E}[1 - X_i + e^t X_i] \quad (\forall x \in [0,1], \quad e^{tx} \leq 1 - x + e^t x)\\
&= [e^{-tq} (1 - p + e^t p)]^m.
\end{align}
$$
Now, the function $ f : t \mapsto e^{-tq} (1 - p + e^t p) = (1-p)e^{-tq} + pe^{t(1-q)} $ reaches its minimum at $ t = \log \frac{q(1-p)}{p(1-q)} $. Plugging in this value of $ t $ in the inequality above yields $ \mathbb{P}[\hat{p} \geq q] \leq e^{-m D(q\|p)} $.

I can follow upto the last step and obtained the same $t$ However when I plug $t = \log \frac{q(1-p)}{p(1-q)}$ into the RHS of equation $\mathbb{P}[e^{tm\hat{p}} \geq e^{tmq}] \leq [e^{-tq} (1 - p + e^t p)]^m$ I dont get anything close to a KL-divergence. I also tried plugging in numerical examples for $p,q$ and found that in general:
$$[e^{-tq} (1 - p + e^t p)]^m \neq e^{-mD(q\|p)}.$$ What am I doing wrong?

Pushing the multiplying $1-p$ and $p$ into their respective exponents, the expression we want to understand is $$ \exp\left(- q \log \frac{q(1-p)}{p(1-q)} + \log(1-p)\right) + \exp\left( (1-q) \log \frac{q(1-p)}{p(1-q)} + \log p\right).$$
The first term in the above can be written as $$\exp\left( (1-q) \log(1-p) - q \log \frac{q}{p} -q\log\frac1{1-q} \right) \\ = \exp\left( -\log(1/1-q) + (1-q) \log\frac{1-p}{1-q} - q \log \frac qp\right) = (1-q)e^{-D(q\|p)}.$$
The second term is similarly $$ \exp\left((1-q) \log \frac{1-p}{1-q} + (1-q) \log q + q \log p \right) \\ = \exp\left( \log q - q \log \frac{q}{p} - (1-q) \log \frac{1-q}{1-p}\right) = q e^{-D(q\|p)},$$ and so the sum of these two terms is just $e^{-D(q\|p)}$.

ah thank you so much! I was discouraged by seeing the sum of exponentials and couldn't think of a way of unite them to get the KL...
